# How Can I Get <div> height in my .ts file

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic tags to design my application and at one of my screen I want `<div>` tag's height and want to calculate next view height

Any Idea how to get `<div>` height at runtime in my **.ts** file?

**Code:**

```
 <div *ngIf="affectedItemsViewShowFlag" class="affected-items-list-style" [style.height.%]="height">
      <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'affected item'" class="list-style">
        <ion-grid no-padding>
          <ion-row *ngFor="let keyValue of affectedItemJsonKeyValues">
            <ion-col col-6>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label class="key-font-style">{{ keyValue }}</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
              <ion-item class="column-remove-padding">
                <ion-label class="value-font-style">{{ faCaseDetails.affected_item[keyValue] }}</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
```

in above `<div>` my height dynamic like `[style.height.%]="height"` and I am fetching this from my **ts** file.

But before that, I want `<div>` height of the previous one segment.

any help appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong, but why can't you use vanila js to get a height of an element inside your .ts?

Comment: I dont know vanila js can you please guide me on this ?

Comment: Try to use this `var height = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight; ` directly in your .ts file

Comment: its working perfectly Thanks @JavaEvgen

Comment: Are you trying to scroll to the bottom of the window after getting the height of the <div>

Comment: no not trying to scroll to bottom of the window but I have multiple segment and in all segment i have <div> so based on 1st segment <div> height i want to calculate 2nd segment <div> height and set to that <div> height dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though `var height = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;` would work, that's not the best way to access to the DOM in an Angular application.

**Direct access to the DOM must be avoided when possible.**

A better way to do that would be by using a template variable in the view:

```
<ion-header>
...
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>    
  <div #target style="background-color:yellow; height:100px;"></div>    
  <p>The height of the div is: {{ result }}px</p>
</ion-content>
```

And then using `ViewChild` to get that element in the component code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('target') targetElement: any;    
  result: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get the height of the element
    const height = this.targetElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight;

    // Here you can use the height!
    this.result = height;
    console.log(height);
  }

}
```

Please take a look at this **[working stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-div-height-from-code)**.

Comment: Nice its working as expected Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Glad to hear that @Gustavo :)

Comment: Not working getting error: 
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')"

Comment: @SirajAli for some reason the element is undefined in your code. Make sure you try to get the `nativeElement` **after** the element was rendered in the view (for example if there's an `*ngIf` in any of their parents).